# Where can I find older versions of Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

You may need to use an older version of the Eclipse ADT in case you have a custom setup that depends on Google's earlier build system standards.  Where on the web can you find the older versions of the ADT and how do you install them in Eclipse?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can find the old versions of the ADT at the following URLs (it looks like Google keeps them around, but doesn't advertise how to locate them).

- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.5.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.6.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.7.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.8.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.9.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.1.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-14.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-15.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.3.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.0.1.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.1.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.1.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.4.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.5.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.2.0.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.2.1.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip

You can use these in Eclipse by first downloading the desired ADT zip to your local drive, then choosing "Install New Software", "Add Site", "Archive".

Comment: Awesome. The tip on choosing the downloaded Zip file is very good.

Comment: And if my eclipse can't running and show error and -clean not working and removing some plugins not working agian, how can io install this downloaded ADT?

Comment: And how to get old SDK (Revisions)?

Comment: I;ve downgraded the SDK to 22.3.0, but when I try to load the archive file for ADT 22.3.0, it fails with one of the lines reading `"Android DDMS" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed.`  And I can't uninstall 22.6 because it says another application is dependent on it.

Answer (score 7):

this page always has the latest ADT available as a zip file

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

and you can use the wayback machine to find older versions of that page, with a link to the older version of ADT

http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: The zip file can be found under the section titled "Troubleshooting ADT Installation"

Comment: you can try this:
https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.6.zip
which has worked for me