# How to downgrade Android ADT?

Tags: android, adt, downgrade

The newest Android ADT update ruined my life. Is there any way to download and install the old ADTs (before 14) to a clean Eclipse install? I didn't find the file anywhere.

EDIT: I don't need this one anymore but if somebody knows the answer, go on and say it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which are the issues you have to deal with to see if we could help you in using ADT 15 / SDK Tools 15? (I agree changes between 13 and 14/15 are numerous and may be disappointing)

Comment: I think it is unsafe to use not-the-latest ADT. You may want to find the root cause of your issue or just do a clean reinstall of all the tools.

Comment: I have another question here related to the issue and as I have said there, I haven't found any fix to my bugs though I have scanned through all the forums and stack overflow topics I was able to find. I think I have fixed a big stack of problems already but I still can't compile any of my projects (even a new Android project won't compile!)

Comment: Btw total re-install of all tools fixed part of my problem and deleting debug.keystore fixed the rest so I don't need this advice anymore. Thanks Alex!

Comment: Old ADTs are not available though the ADT Plugin site. The new ADT also ruined my life, it's doesnt goes well with third party jar libs.

Comment: @Finnboy11 ADT "upgrades" [ruin my life](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11008325/576267) too. +1 for stating the obvious.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I find how (if your eclipse had once the old version installed).

On Eclipse go to Help-> About-> "Installed Softwares" > Installation History

Found the state where the plugin has the version you want and revert to it.

Comment: This can be a bit tricky as I first tried to solve my problem by deleting Eclipse but it's great to know this if the same happens in the future. Thanks!

Comment: "Installed Softwares" located in Help -> About

Answer (score 32):

I also made the mistake of upgrading to the latest ADT.  Heres a quick way to get your old one back.

1. Head over to http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes and pick which pick which version you want to use again.
2. Create your download url: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-##.#.#.zip.  Google uses the version number for the downloads, so if you need 10.0.1, your download would be http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip.
3. Uninstall the current ADT version in Eclipse.
4. Install the new version as an archive!

Comment: yeah, problem is: he doesn't know how to "Uninstall the current ADT version in Eclipse."

Comment: If anyone's interested, the download link for r18 is: dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r18-linux.tgz