# Android ADT 11 for Eclipse

Tags: android, adt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find older versions of Eclipse ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt)

How can I download `ADT 11` and Android SDK of June 2011 for eclipse. I know latest one is better but I am total beginner in Android and the tutorials I am following to learn it use ADT 11. I have installed `ADT 20` but most of the stuff in xml files and others things has been changed. And I am having a hard time learning android because of this.Is this change because of latest `ADT` or `SDK`, so that I uninstall that one inorder to install the previous version.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4710107/1122135

Comment: It doesn't inlucde adt 11 version

Comment: change the number at the end of the URL, ADT-11.0.0.zip works.

Comment: Do I need to uninstall SDK too

Comment: probably, haven't tried it myself but it's very likely to give you an error message saying that there's already a newer version installed.

Comment: OK. SO where can I download android-sdk_r11-windows

Comment: Learn to use Google: http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Android_SDK#Old_versions

Comment: What tutorials are you using that are so out of date?

Comment: @TJThind: In my experience, most tutorials will be "obsolete" purely from the SDK / ADT that they were originally based on. The idea is to see how things are done in them and adapt the technique to the latest platform (if you intend to use them of course)

Comment: I am following tutorials from june 2011. The XML files and their graphical representation is completly changed. Is there any way to bring it back to June 2011 settings. Because of this I am difficulty in learning android.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window => Preferences => Install/Update` It will display new dialog 
In new dialog select `Installation History` tab. Here you can see list of update and installation with date. Select the tool which you want to uninstall.

After uninstalling, for add ADT plugins you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4710123/630668 answer.