# Android old interface for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Two months ago, I set up Eclipse Indigo to build android application. Then i got some problems with my computer so I uninstalled it.

I downloaded Eclipse Indigo again and tried to set up Eclipse but the interface has changed. There are some additional folders and options. I followed [newboston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPFUTJgvVpQ) tutorials  for installation.

So, my question is how can I get back to the old interface like the one in the tutorial? I don't like the new one. Here is how it looks in the new interface. I've also attached a video which has the old interface.

[image]

Comment: What part of it do you not like? Everything appears normally but you might have an additional toolbar activated or something? If you're wanting to edit the layout with a text editor, when you click on the file to open, right click -> Open in text editor.

Comment: yeah toolbar and some other features too ? is it poosible that i can have the older interface .. ? i am getting error when i am hardcoding the string like that android:text:"total is zero ".. its showing me an error a blue triangle .. and the error is displaying on the output screen too .. you can see that

Comment: so i think may be in future i get some other errors too so thats why i want to have an old interface

Comment: @mynameisjohn What I think your referring to as the "blue triangle" is only a warning. Yes, when you hardcode a string into an layout XML, by default, Android doesn't like that. According to Android conventions, it's much neater and cleaner to add your `strings.xml` file. Don't ask me why they do it like that, but that's how they like it up in Google.

Comment: ok thanks to you .. but you didnt give me an answer .. is it posible to go back an old interface ?

Comment: @RobAveryIV They do that to make the process of localising your app much quicker. Of course if you are completely sure that your app will only be in one language, then you can just use hard coded strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem of Eclipse. This is related to [Android Development Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)(ADT), which is a plugin for Eclipse.

If you really want to go back to previous version of ADT, please take a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt/4710123#4710123) to get old versions of ADT.