# Setting up Eclipse for Android Development and testing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

As the title suggests, the issue I am having is in setting up Eclipse for Android Development and testing.  There are two installations that need to be in sync.  There is the ADT and there is the SDK.  The problem I seem to be having stems from the fact that the latest version of the ADT is not compliant with what I need to do.  I cannot use the ADT version 23.  Instead, I need to use version 22.

The problem is in the fact that the SDK and the ADT have to be the same versions.  How do I get and use version 22 of the SDK for android development for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clean out the ADT install features ( DDMS, traceview, etc ) by displaying Help installed features then hilite them and press the 'uninstall' button.

ANDROID ADT etc now cleaned out of eclipse.

download install from archive the following link:

dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz

That will install correct SDK.

Then you have to add ADT to eclipse without it default to R 23 where you will get the 'incompatible ' message list......

I think [this will help you](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419) with the last item on reverting ADT to R 22

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt  look at accept answr there... goto ADT-22.6.3.zip

Comment: This looks like a success.  I downloaded the ADT file and unzipped it.  The contents are 3 folders: features, plugins, and web; and two files: index.html and site.xml.  Using Eclipse, which directory should I point to.  I guess the root.  I will try this now.

Comment: No . look at updating eclipse from local archive.

Comment: I need to get version 19.0.2 of the Android SDK Platform tools.  It is a long story but basicaly the OS usins glibc version 2.5.  So I need an older version of the SDK.  Google does not tell me directly where I can find it.

Comment: Play around with download links for SDK sub in your version to get 19.