# I need an older version of the Android SDK. Where can I find it?

Tags: android, sdk

I need to get version 19.0.2 of the Android SDK Platform tools.  It is a long story but basicaly the OS usins glibc version 2.5.  So I need an older version of the SDK.  Google does not tell me directly where I can find it.

Comment: why not try using the SDK manager.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work. There seems to be a difference between the "Android SDK Platform-tools" and the "Android SDK build tools" Even the manager seems to be impacted by the version numbers.

Answer (score 3):

In the Android SDK manager, you can download the 19.0.2 of the android sdk.

The SDK manager is located `{ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY}/tools/android`

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Download Old SDK image]

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work.  There seems to be a difference between the "Android SDK Platform-tools" and the "Android SDK build tools"  Even the manager seems to be impacted by the version numbers.

Comment: let me explain.  This snapshot shows that I have the "Android SDK Build Tools 19.0.2 installed" but this is not the same as having the right Android SDK Platform-tools 19.0.2 http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Amazon/Capture_05_zps4e423ce7.png

Answer (score 0):

To use a specific version of the Build Tools in your application project. Refer :

https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

[image]

Comment: @xarzu You do not need to download it if you already have it in your SDK Manager

Comment: I have to use a specific version of the Android SDK Platform tools.  If you use a particular version of the sdk manager, it defaults to a particular version that you cannot uninstall from the manager.  THe only option is to delete the folder and start over with an earlier version of the sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt) answer for getting earlier versions of the Android ADT plugin for Eclipse.

Then just download the SDK you need after installing the ADT Version that you want. Keep in mind that prior to rev 23, the most recent version was 22.6.3, so you can simply change the URL to those numbers and get the latest version prior to the L Preview release.

Comment: I need an older version of the Android SDK, not the ADT

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the repository descriptors:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml

Maybe it works when if you download and install it manually:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip