# Eclipse:This Android SDK requires Android Developer tools 23.0.0 or above?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am attempting to set the path to my `SDK` in order to use it within `Eclipse Luna`, However whenever I do so I get the error:

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer tools 23.0.0 or above, please update ADT to latest version.
```

The issue is that **I do not want to update to the the newest version** of the `ADT plugin`, I am purposely using the older version as it is the version compatible with a `plugin tool` I want to use.

I have installed various `SDK build tools` versions (namely Rev 21) using `SDK manager` in order to try and make it compatible with the ADT plugin, however this has not worked.

How can I make the old ADT and SDK **compatible**? Do I need to download a complete older version of the SDK, rather than just older verion of the build tools?

**Screenshot of error:**

[image]

Comment: `I do not want to use the newest version of the ADT` ... **WHY**? You should **ALWAYS** use the latest release of ADT.

Comment: Because I am trying to use an old version of a plugin/dropin tool for eclipse that is only compatible with an older ADT! :(

Comment: Look for a newer plugin release or change plugin to something more modern.

Comment: can this be solved without updating the ADT?

Comment: Obviously, not (AFAIK).

Comment: Surely changing the SDK to an older version would make it compatible with an older version of the ADT?

Comment: My question is why do you want to **uninstall and reinstall ALL**, when **you can get rid of or get a new version or use a different plugin**...

Comment: I dont want to get the new version, the 3rd party plugin that I am using is only compatible with an older version of the ADT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read how to revert eclipse to older versions of ( ADT, SDK )

get the downloads and install them.

dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz

dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r21.0.1-linux.tgz

--EDIT-- i use linux above are 2 linux links for dwnload respective version.
substitute your OS and maybe google a little and you will have the link for R21 on your OS...

[Where can I find older versions of Eclipse ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt)

you can hunt for other, older versions of SDK dwnloads. sample link provided

Comment: Can you please provide me with a link to the Android SDK tools r21.0.0 in you answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks but It is actually the r21.0.0 version for windows that I am looking for?