# Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity.onCreate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I am newbiw to android.Done a new app,using `http://myaucir.blogspot.in/2014/08/google-play-game-services-and-admob-in.html` tutorial i did admob related coding.

But i am getting error

```
Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity.onCreate
```

Checked the solution

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!search/Could$20not$20find$20class$20$27com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView/google-admob-ads-sdk/_AlmfhrsR_E/GJwoTpOSBoAJ
```

By this solution i found that,use a old adt and sdk. But i am started  newly, so recently i downloaded adt and sdk.So how can i get old adt and sdk
Can anyone help me to resolve .

Comment: Did you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt

Comment: I just tried this.But in sdk 'i am getting This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.  Please update ADT to the latest version. ' error

Comment: Just follow the official google guide for admob

Comment: could you explain how you imported the google play services into your project? could be an error there! which ide are you using?

Comment: using http://myaucir.blogspot.in/2014/08/google-play-game-services-and-admob-in.html i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this error by, uninstalled eclipse.Download a eclipse `http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html`  and updated libgdx by new version

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that you have to use a recent version of ADT not an older one as you asked in your question.
Try this : http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: I used Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0,Due to the error unistalled  23.0.0,installed 22.3.0 that time i got version error.